# Change a record in Postgresql database automatically if it exceeds preset time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am building a sudo parking management system. I am trying to build the ability to change the availability status on a Postgresql record when the time runs out. I want the availability status to change to `AVAILABLE` 24 hours after the record was created.

Any tips hints or trick on achieving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can easily implement a background job to do this. 
Check http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

Comment: Thats the link I neded! thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty simple task.

Set up the rake task, updating the records. For example:

```
# lib/tasks/update_avilability.rake
ParkingSpace.where('created_at > ?', 1.day).find_each do |ps|
  ps.update(status: 'AVAILABLE')
end
```

Then create a cron job, and run this task, say, once each 10 minutes.

You can use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem for this:

```
#config/schedule.rb
every 10.minutes do
  rake 'update_avilability', output: 'log/cron.log'
end
```

It is how it could look, in general. Of course, there are things to work on and set up according to your application.

See [docs for background jobs in Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html).

Comment: so i create lib/tasks in my app directory? and then just create a new schedule in the config folder?

Comment: disregard i found what i needed